# get_terms return errors

Tags: wordpress, get, taxonomy

Hi when i try to `get_terms();` in theme options via this code

```
$catalogs_terms = get_terms( 'catalogs' );
   $mycatalogs = array( -1 => 'Select a catalog' );
   if ( $catalogs_terms ) {
      foreach ( $catalogs_terms as $catalog_term ) {
         $mycatalogs[$catalog_term->term_id] = $catalog_term->name;
      }
   }
```

return empty but this code is working fine every where in pages etc.
when i try to `print_r( $catalogs_terms )` output i am getting errors

```
Array ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid Taxonomy ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )
```

i don't understand where am i wrong?
my function for register taxonomy

```
    add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies', 0 );

function my_taxonomies() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Catalogs', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Catalog', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Catalogs', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Catalogs', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Catalog', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Catalog:', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Catalog', 'mytextdomain' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Catalog', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Catalog', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Catalog Name', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Catalogs', 'mytextdomain' ),
    );  

    // register catalogs hierarchical (like categories)
    register_taxonomy( 'catalogs',
        array( 'news' ),
        array( 'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'catalogs' )
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this with help of [t31os](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1468/t31os)

you can finde more [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13480/get-terms-return-errors/13482#13482)

Answer (score 3):

This should get you on the right track...

```
$qt = 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->terms.' AS t INNER JOIN '.$wpdb->term_taxonomy.' AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy =  "<-- your taxonomy -->" AND tt.count > 0 ORDER BY  t.term_id DESC LIMIT 0 , 30';

$terms = $wpdb->get_results($qt, ARRAY_A);
```